# How to test a store update triggered by action creator in ComponentDidMount

Tags: react-native, react-redux, jestjs, integration-testing, enzyme

I am trying to test a connected component that fetches an image from the bing API to set as background image on `ComponentDidMount`. The test is quite simple, I am using Enzyme to render the component redux-mock-store to mock my redux store. The expectation should just check the the value of the uri key of the source prop of `ImageBackground` component is correctly set. Here's how the component looks like (I deleted most of the irrelevent code) :

```
class LoginForm extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.fetchImageOfTheDay()
  }
  render() {
    if (this.props.loading) {
      return <Spinner size="large" />;
    }
    else {
      return (
        <ImageBackground style={styles.containerStyle} source={{uri: this.props.backgroundImage ? this.props.backgroundImage : ""}}>
        </ImageBackground>
      )
    }
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const { username, password } = state.authentication;
  const {error, loading, backgroundImage} = state
  return { username, password, error, loading, backgroundImage };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { loginUser, authUpdate, fetchImageOfTheDay })(LoginForm);
```

fetchImage of the day is responsible for getting the image and updating backgroundImage on the store :

```
export const fetchImageOfTheDay = () =>{
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios.get('http://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=js&idx=0&n=1')
      .then(response => fetchImageOfTheDaySuccess(dispatch, response))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
    };
}
const fetchImageOfTheDaySuccess = (dispatch, data) => {
  console.log("DATA", data.data.images[0].url)
  dispatch({
    type: SET_BACKGROUND_IMAGE,
    payload: data.data.images[0].url
  })
}
```

Here's my test, everytime I check the uri I get an "" and not the expected data I am mocking using moxios ( the mock actually works as  `console.log("DATA", data.data.images[0].url)` is actually printing what it should in `fetchImageOfTheDaySuccess`.

```
let store
const setup = (initialState = {}) => {
  store = makeMockStore(initialState);
  const wrapper = shallow(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <LoginForm/>
    </Provider>).dive()
  return wrapper
}
let initialState
beforeEach(() => {
  initialState = { error: false, loading: false, authentication: { username: "", password: ""}, backgroundImage: null}
})
test('it fetches and displays an ImageBackground', (done) => {
  moxios.install()
  moxios.stubRequest('http://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=js&idx=0&n=1', {
    status: 200,
    response: getImageOftheDayMock
  })

  wrapper = setup(initialState).dive()

  moxios.wait(()=>{
    wrapper.update()
    console.log(store.getState())
    console.log(wrapper.find(ImageBackground).prop('source').uri)
    expect(wrapper.find(ImageBackground).prop('source').uri).toBe('/th?id=OHR.RedRocksArches_EN-GB2044389872_1920x1080.jpg&rf=LaDigue_1920x1080.jpg&pid=hp')
    done()
    moxios.uninstall()
  })
})
```

Here's makeMockStore :

```
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

const middlewares = [thunk] // add your middlewares like `redux-thunk`
const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares)
export const makeMockStore = (state = {}) => {
  return mockStore({
    ...state
  })
}
```

it seems that the store is never updated even if I call `wrapper.update()`. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: have you tried making `componentDidMount` async and `await`ing the call to `fetchImageOfTheDay` ?

Comment: @WillJenkins I dont think it is necessary as I am using redux-thunk middleware to deal with async actions. The functionnality actually works in my app code, it's the test that I am failing to writte

Comment: @WillJenkins just tried, and it doesnt work any better